# Get group of records by theirs group_id in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

For example I have table *Products* with data like below:

```
-----------------------------------------
id |  name            | price | group_id
-----------------------------------------
 1 | iPhone 8         |  xxx  |   
 2 | iPhone 7 black   |  xxx  |   0001 
 3 | iPhone 7 white   |  xxx  |   0001
 4 | iPhone 7 red     |  xxx  |   0001
 5 | iPhone 6 gol     |  xxx  |   0002
 6 | iPhone 6 white   |  xxx  |   0002
 7 | iPhone 6 silver  |  xxx  |   0002
 8 | iPhone 5  SE     |  xxx  |   
 9 | iPhone 5 gold    |  xxx  |   0003
 10| iPhone 5 white   |  xxx  |   0003
 11| iPhone 5 gary    |  xxx  |   0003
 12| Samsung Galaxy   |  xxx  |
-----------------------------------------
```

I need to show products list(with related if exists) with limit 3 per page.

**For example**:

*First page:*

- iPhone 8
- iPhone 7 black and their group (iPhone 7 white, iPhone 7 red)
- iPhone 6 gold and their group (iPhone 6 white, iPhone 6 silver)

*Second Page:*

- iPhone 5 SE
- iPhone 5 gold and their group (iPhone 5 white, iPhone 5 gary)
- Samsung galaxy

How its possible to do that using MySQL ?

Comment: Selecting the top N per group in MySQL is a topic which is already well covered on Stack Overflow.  In any case, why do iPhone 8 and iPhone 5 SE not belong to a group?

Comment: iPhone 5 SE, iPhone 8 and Samsung Galaxy not have products which need show together on page

Comment: Like wise, pagination is thoroughly covered elsewhere